# Is it possible to launch a link into the Android WebView from an HTML page

Tags: android, html

So I'll try to make it clear.

Is it possible to create an HTML file to open in Chrome (or any other web browser) and add a link inside that HTML file that when clicked open in the Android WebView.

So what I want to do is create an HTML file. That includes a link

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">Example Website</a>
```

I want that link (example.com) to open in the Android Web View.

I don't know if its even possible, but if anyone got a solution, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: WebViwes only exist inside Android apps, so do you want to devlope such an app?

Comment: @Robert I've got an Android device that is secured by Knox and belongs to an organization, any webpage on Chrome doesn't open except for what the admins decide.

But... we used to open webpages using the webviewer from using Microsoft Teams and just jumping ad redirecting inside till we reach Google.

Recently, they uninstalled Microsoft teams, so if I could run a webpage that opens the Android WebView I could do the same process and reach Google again. A note to take, I can't install apps. Just transferring files and HTML files do work. If there isn't a way, thank you anyways.